# Removing FAB when reaching end of RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create a screen where there is a Recycler View with a fixed number of elements (4 elements) and a FAB button (bottom right position).

I would like to remove the FAB button (translation or reveal effect) when I scoll down and reach the last element of the RecyclerView.

I would also like to have the FAB coming back again when I scroll up after the end is reached.

Could you please tell me how I could do this.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Add `addOnScrollListener` to the `RecyclerView`.

```
mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
}

@Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
    mOnScreenItems = mRecyclerView.getChildCount();
    mTotalItemsInList = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
    mFirstVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
    if (mLoadingItems) {
        if (mTotalItemsInList > mPreviousTotal+1) {
            mLoadingItems = false;
            mPreviousTotal = mTotalItemsInList;
        }
    }
    if (!mLoadingItems && (mTotalItemsInList - mOnScreenItems) <= (mFirstVisibleItem + mVisibleThreshold)) {
        // end reached
        mLoadingItems = true;
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
//Add this to your Recyclerview
recyclerview.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

//Tocheck if  recycler is on top
if(layoutManager.firstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()==0){
//Its at top ..
fab.show();
}

//Tocheck if  recycler is on bottom
    if(layoutManager.lastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()==data.size()-1){
    //Its at bottom ..
     fab.hide();
    }
```